# Two elements in array whose xor is maximum

Tags: arrays, algorithm, bit-manipulation, xor

Given an array of integers ,You have to find two elements whose XOR is maximum.

There is naive approach --just by picking each   element and xoring with other elements and then comparing the results to find the pair.

Other than this ,Is there any efficient  algorithm?

Comment: A good bet is taking the largest and smallest value since the small value's bits are then unlikely to 'destroy' the 'good' high bits of the high value during the xor process.

Comment: failed for arr={8,4,2}  answer is 8^4 and 4 is not smallest...

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: It'll definitely be a pair of numbers, one of which has the top bit set and the other has it reset.

Comment: Are duplicate elements allowed or all integers are unique?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I think I have a `O(n lg U)` algorithm for this, where `U` is the largest number.  The idea is similar to *user949300*'s, but with a bit more detail.

The intuition is as follows.  When you're XORing two numbers together, to get the maximum value, you want to have a `1` at the highest possible position, and then of the pairings that have a `1` at this position, you want a pairing with a `1` at the next possible highest position, etc.

So the algorithm is as follows.  Begin by finding the highest `1` bit anywhere in the numbers (you can do this in time `O(n lg U)` by doing `O(lg U)` work per each of the `n` numbers).  Now, split the array into two pieces - one of the numbers that have a `1` in that bit and the group with `0` in that bit.  Any optimal solution must combine a number with a `1` in the first spot with a number with a `0` in that spot, since that would put a `1` bit as high as possible.  Any other pairing has a `0` there.

Now, recursively, we want to find the pairing of numbers from the `1` and `0` group that has the highest `1` in them.  To do this, of these two groups, split them into four groups:

- Numbers starting with `11`
- Numbers starting with `10`
- Numbers starting with `01`
- Numbers starting with `00`

If there are any numbers in the `11` and `00` group or in the `10` and `01` groups, their XOR would be ideal (starting with `11`).  Consequently, if either of those pairs of groups isn't empty, recursively compute the ideal solution from those groups, then return the maximum of those subproblem solutions.  Otherwise, if both groups are empty, this means that all the numbers must have the same digit in their second position.  Consequently, the optimal XOR of a number starting with `1` and a number starting with `0` will end up having the next second bit cancel out, so we should just look at the third bit.

This gives the following recursive algorithm that, starting with the two groups of numbers partitioned by their MSB, gives the answer:

- Given group `1` and group `0` and a bit index `i`:

  - If the bit index is equal to the number of bits, return the XOR of the (unique) number in the `1` group and the (unique) number in the `0` group.
  - Construct groups `11`, `10`, `01`, and `00` from those groups.
  - If group `11` and group `00` are nonempty, recursively find the maximum XOR of those two groups starting at bit `i + 1`.
  - If group `10` and group `01` are nonempty, recursively find the maximum XOR of those two groups, starting at bit `i + 1`.
  - If either of the above pairings was possible, then return the maximum pair found by the recursion.
  - Otherwise, all of the numbers must have the same bit in position `i`, so return the maximum pair found by looking at bit `i + 1` on groups `1` and `0`.

To start off the algorithm, you can actually just partition the numbers from the initial group into two groups - numbers with MSB `1` and numbers with MSB `0`.  You then fire off a recursive call to the above algorithm with the two groups of numbers.

As an example, consider the numbers  `5  1  4  3  0  2`.  These have representations

```
101  001  100   011   000   010
```

We begin by splitting them into the `1` group and the `0` group:

```
101  100
001  011  000  010
```

Now, we apply the above algorithm.  We split this into groups `11`, `10`, `01`, and `00`:

```
11:
10:  101  100
01:  011  010
00:  000  001
```

Now, we can't pair any `11` elements with `00` elements, so we just recurse on the `10` and `01` groups.  This means we construct the `100`, `101`, `010`, and `011` groups:

```
101: 101
100: 100
011: 011
010: 010
```

Now that we're down to buckets with just one element in them, we can just check the pairs `101` and `010` (which gives `111`) and `100` and `011` (which gives `111`).  Either option works here, so we get that the optimal answer is `7`.

Let's think about the running time of this algorithm.  Notice that the maximum recursion depth is `O(lg U)`, since there are only `O(log U)` bits in the numbers.  At each level in the tree, each number appears in exactly one recursive call, and each of the recursive calls does work proportional to the total number of numbers in the `0` and `1` groups, because we need to distribute them by their bits.  Consequently, there are `O(log U)` levels in the recursion tree, and each level does `O(n)` work, giving a total work of `O(n log U)`.

Hope this helps!  This was an awesome problem!

Comment: I also considered looking at more than one bit (11 vs. 10) and my gut feeling was that, at that point, it might be faster to just blast through all the combinations.  And I didn't want to think that hard and fix all the bugs that would get created either  :-)  Obviously depends on how large N is, for huge N your approach would be faster.

Comment: What do you mean there are O(log U) bits in the numbers?  By definition, there is a number with U bits, so that's O(U).  I think your running time is at least O(NU).

Comment: @DavidGrayson- Assuming that the largest number present is the number U (as in the upper limit of the universe {1, 2, 3, ..., U}), then the numbers each have O(log U) bits.  This is to point out that the number of bits is logarithmic in the size of the largest number.  So yes, if there are U bits, then the runtime is O(NU).  I'm just using U as the largest number rather than a bit count.

Comment: You assume that the set of numbers with a 0 in the highest relevant bit position is non-empty. Also, I don't believe that you can determine the highest bit set in a U-bit number in O(log(U)) time.

Comment: Oh, I see the problem with the log(U). It's your first line... it should be "U is the upper bound on the numbers" not "U is the number of bits in the largest number". log(U) is the number of bits, not U.

Comment: This algorithm fails for the following cases: [4,6,7] ; [8,10,2], [14, 15, 9, 3, 2] and [15, 15, 9, 3, 2]. Checkout this analysis and a fixed version of this algorithm: https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/64431/a-solution-based-on-bartoszkp-s-with-missing-test-cases.

Comment: @templatetypedef After sub-dividing by the way you presented in your above answer, How should we decide on the which 2 pairs of numbers to xor ?

Answer (score 7):

This can be solved in `O(NlogN)` time complexity using [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

- Construct a trie. For each integer key, each node of the trie will hold every bit(0 or 1) starting from most significant bit.
- Now for each `arr[i]` element of `arr[0, 1, ..... N]`

  - Perform query to retrieve the maximum xor value possible for `arr[i]`. We know xor of different type of bits(`0 ^ 1` or `1 ^ 0`) is always `1`. So during query for each bit, try to traverse node holding opposite bit. This will make that particular bit `1` result in maximizing xor value. If there is no node with opposite bit, only then traverse the same bit node.
  - After query, insert `arr[i]` into trie.
  - For each element, keep track the maximum Xor value possible.
  - During walking through each node, build the other key for which the Xor is being maximized.

For `N` elements, we need one query(`O(logN)`) and one insertion(`O(logN)`) for each element. So the overall time complexity is `O(NlogN)`.

You can find nice pictorial explanation on how it works [in this thread](https://threads-iiith.quora.com/Tutorial-on-Trie-and-example-problems).

Here is C++ implementation of the above algorithm:

```
const static int SIZE = 2;
const static int MSB = 30;
class trie {
private:
    struct trieNode {
        trieNode* children[SIZE];
        trieNode() {
            for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
                children[i] = nullptr;
            }
        }
        ~trieNode() {
            for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
                delete children[i];
                children[i] = nullptr;
            }
        }
    };
    trieNode* root;
public:
    trie(): root(new trieNode()) {
    }
    ~trie() {
        delete root;
        root = nullptr;
    }

    void insert(int key) {
        trieNode* pCrawl = root;
        for(int i = MSB; i >= 0; --i) {
            bool bit = (bool)(key & (1 << i));
            if(!pCrawl->children[bit]) {
                pCrawl->children[bit] = new trieNode();
            }
            pCrawl = pCrawl->children[bit];
        }
    }

    int query(int key, int& otherKey) {
        int Xor = 0;
        trieNode *pCrawl = root;
        for(int i = MSB; i >= 0; --i) {
            bool bit = (bool)(key & (1 << i));
            if(pCrawl->children[!bit]) {
                pCrawl = pCrawl->children[!bit];
                Xor |= (1 << i);
                if(!bit) {
                    otherKey |= (1 << i); 
                } else {
                    otherKey &= ~(1 << i);
                }
            } else {
                if(bit) {
                    otherKey |= (1 << i); 
                } else {
                    otherKey &= ~(1 << i);
                }
                pCrawl = pCrawl->children[bit];
            }
        }
        return Xor;
    }
};

pair<int, int> findMaximumXorElements(vector<int>& arr) {
    int n = arr.size();
    int maxXor = 0;
    pair<int, int> result; 
    if(n < 2) return result;
    trie* Trie = new trie();
    Trie->insert(0); // insert 0 initially otherwise first query won't find node to traverse
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int elem = 0;
        int curr = Trie->query(arr[i], elem);
        if(curr > maxXor) {
            maxXor = curr;
            result = {arr[i], elem};
        }
        Trie->insert(arr[i]);
    }
    delete Trie;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Amazing solution! I find your answer to be the easiest to understand in this thread. I have a question and, sorry in advance for necro-bumping, but: where does the **logarithmic** part come from? I mean, for each element in the array, we perform insertions and queries that take exactly `C` steps each (breadth of the integer encoded, `32` in our example), so shouldn't our complexity be like, `N * C` steps for the insertions plus `N * C` steps for the queries, resulting in `O(2 * (N * C)) <=> O(N)`?

Answer (score 5):

Ignoring the sign bit, one of the values must be one of the values with the highest significant bit set.  *Unless all the values have that bit set*, in which case you go to the next highest significant bit that isn't set in all the values.  So you could pare down the possibilities for the 1st value by looking at the HSB.  For example, if the possibilities are

```
0x100000
0x100ABC
0x001ABC
0x000ABC
```

The 1st value of the max pair must be either 0x100000 or 0x10ABCD.

@internal Server Error  I don't think smallest is necessarily correct.  I don't have a great idea for paring down the 2nd value.  Just any value that *isn't* in the list of possible 1st values.  In my example, 0x001ABC or 0x000ABC.

Answer (score 4):

A very interesting problem!
Here is my idea:

- First build a binary tree from all the numbers by using the binary
  representation and sort them into the tree most significant bit first
  (add leading zeros to match the longest number). When done each path
  from the root to any leaf represents one number from the original
  set.
- Let a and b be pointers to a tree node and initialize them at the root.
- Now move a and b down the tree, trying to use opposite edges at each step, i.e. if a moves down a 0-edge, b moves down a 1-edge unless its not possible.

If a and b reach a leaf, the should point to two numbers with "very few" identical bits.

I just made this algorithm up and do not know if its correct or how to prove it. However it should be in O(n) running time.

Comment: I like the idea of making the tree, but if both A and B can travel to the 0 or 1 node, what do you do?  I think you have to try both possibilities to see which one is better.

Comment: I don't think it is a problem, because A and B are indistinguishable, i.e. A -> 1, B -> 0 and A -> 0, B -> 1 are really the same case, right?

Comment: Yeah, as soon as you advance past the first step, A and B are at different locations in your tree so it makes a difference which one you move to where.  You're on the right track but you just need a little more complexity.

Comment: Actually the complexity is O(n * log(U)), where U is the largest given number, similar to templatetypedef 's answer.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Check this. Here is an implemented form of your solution. https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-xor-of-two-numbers-in-an-array/discuss/795098/C-16ms-runtime-O(n)-solution-beats-100-of-submissions

Answer (score 1):

Make a recursive function that takes two lists of integers, A and B, as its arguments.  As its return value, it returns two integers, one from A and one from B, which maximize the XOR of the two.  If all the integers are 0, return (0,0).  Otherwise, the function does some processing and calls itself recursively twice, but with smaller integers.  In one of the recursive calls, it considers taking an integer from list A to supply a 1 to bit k, and in the other call it considers taking an integer from list B to supply a 1 to bit k.

I don't have time now to fill in the details, but maybe this will be enough for to see the answer?  Also, I'm not sure if the run time will be better than N^2, but it probably will be.

Answer (score -3):

We can find the maximum number in O(n) time then loop through the array doing xor with each element. Assuming xor operation cost is O(1) we can find max xor of two numbers in O(n) time.

Comment: I'm curious how you prove that the largest number must be part of the pair having the maximum xor result. I'm sure that this is not correct.